# How to use foundations reveal modals?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

as cake3 is using foundation framework, how can I use the reveal moadl function?

I tried simply copy and paste this to my view:

```
<p><a data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</a></p>

<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
  <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
  <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

But when I test it, I don't get any error but also the div is visible and not hidden and the "Click me for a modal" does also nothing.

Do I need to include any further files on order to use this in cake?

Comment: This has little to do with CakePHP, except -perhaps- for the helpers to load the external libraries (`.js` and `.css` files). Make sure you are loading them. For this purpose, you can use plain HTML for the time being, so that you can do some testing.

Comment: As the framework is present, is this only the foundation css? 

Because, when I include these:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.1/foundation.min.js
and
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.1.1/js/foundation.reveal.js

the modal is still not working? What version of foundation is included in cake? Maybe the 5.x?

Comment: Cake3s default baked views and templates are based on Zurb Foundation, you can use whatever you want in your project.